# T-SQL MDQ.RegexReplace Nested

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to clean public company names by removing certain character patterns from the end of the name. Sometimes a company will look like this: Some-Random Company Incorporated Inc. I get rid of special characters and and instances of Inc and Incorporated that appear at the end of the name:

```
MDS_DB.mdq.RegexReplace(MDS_DB.mdq.RegexReplace(COMPANY,
    '[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]', '', 1), 'incorporated$|inc$', '',
    mds_db.mdq.RegexMask(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

Notice that this is already a nested function, and it works correctly resulting in:

```
SomeRandom Company Incorporated
```

Now I want to run the same replacement again to remove the Incorporated that is now at the end of the name due to the prior replacement:

```
MDS_DB.mdq.RegexReplace(MDS_DB.mdq.RegexReplace(MDS_DB.mdq.RegexReplace(COMPANY, '[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]', '', 1), 'incorporated$|inc$', '', mds_db.mdq.RegexMask(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)) ,'incorporated$|inc$', '', mds_db.mdq.RegexMask(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

This does not have the expected effect, and the name remains the same:

```
SomeRandom Company Incorporated
```

Why aren't the nested replaces working in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue here is that the first regex replacement is leaving some trailing whitespace at the end of the name.  So this company name:

```
Some-Random Company Incorporated Inc
```

actually becomes this:

```
Some-Random Company Incorporated[ ]      ([ ] indicates a single space)
```

Try removing the leading whitespace as well:

```
MDS_DB.mdq.RegexReplace(MDS_DB.mdq.RegexReplace(COMPANY,
    '[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]', '', 1), '[ ]+(?:incorporated|inc)$', '',
    mds_db.mdq.RegexMask(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

Note that you could try to remove any number of ending company closings in one go, e.g. try this:

```
MDS_DB.mdq.RegexReplace(MDS_DB.mdq.RegexReplace(COMPANY,
    '[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]', '', 1), '(?:[ ]+(?:incorporated|inc))+$', '',
    mds_db.mdq.RegexMask(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

Untested, but you *might* be able to do just a single replacement:

```
MDS_DB.mdq.RegexReplace(COMPANY,
    '[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]|(?:[ ]+(?:incorporated|inc))+$',
    '',
    mds_db.mdq.RegexMask(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

Comment: that is fantastic - thank you very much. do you mind explaining the regex in the last example? I'm not well versed in regex. would there be a way to combine the replacement of special characters with the other replacements as well?

Comment: @CameronTaylor Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/B4fmaf/1) for the last regex.  It basically just matches any number of spaces followed by `inc` or `incorporated`, that entire quantity one or more times.

Comment: I know this is old but I just used this - fantastic stuff. Bravo.